# Parsing error: Unexpected token prettier/prettier caused by "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Tags: eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I have this vue app which I create using vue cli and the version I use is vue2 (with eslint and prettier).

I could run `npm run serve` and load my page. But in Visual Studio Code, I notice this error:

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/vue/app2/public/index.html",
    "owner": "eslint",
    "code": {
        "value": "prettier/prettier",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#options",
            "path": "/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "options"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Parsing error: Unexpected token",
    "source": "eslint",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 2,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2
}
```

and this is my `.eslintrc.js` which is auto generated when I create the app and I didn't make any changes to it since then.

```
module.exports = {  
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "eslint:recommended", "@vue/prettier"],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off"
  }
};
```

I notice that the error is actually referring to this line instead. Anyone knows what's wrong with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've met a similar issue. It was caused by `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

The fix is quite easy, we need to specify a parser in `prettierrc`, although it is obvious:

```yaml
overrides:
  - files: '*.html'
    options:
      parser: 'html'
  - files: '*.component.html'
    options:
      parser: 'angular'
```

After that prettier is able to format files with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Creds go to [krave1986](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5892#issuecomment-466318688)

Comment: Based off prettier docs, the Parser for html should be inferred automatically. Even after explicitly setting it though, I still get this error. Has there been a regression?

Comment: Which prettier version do you use?

Comment: 2.6.2 is the version

Comment: I have the same issue with graphql queries. This answer solved my problem, I remember not needing to add the overrides to .prettierrc for different file formats to automatically work.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've met a similar problem. It was caused by  in vue3.0 app.

we need a eslint plugin : [eslint-plugin-html](https://github.com/BenoitZugmeyer/eslint-plugin-html/), add the plugin to your ESLint configuration.

```
plugins: ['html'],
```

and you want linting HMTL, use other plugins like [@eslint-html](https://yeonjuan.github.io/html-eslint/)